# Why is my answer triggering a "not properly formatted as code" rejection?

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, markdown, not-properly-formatted-as-code

I'm trying to submit a fairly detailed and well-formatted answer, but the auto-validator complains:

> "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as
>   code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button
>   or the CTRL+K keyboard."

It's pointing to an area that is not code, it's English. All my code areas do appear to be properly indented. How do I appeal? Is there somewhere appropriate to post my full markdown for human review?

Here is the offending markdown, along with a screenshot of the rejection. It is intended to answer [Modify file create / access / write timestamp with python under windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21156145/modify-file-create-access-write-timestamp-with-python-under-windows)

[image: validator warning]

```
There are two places where you might want to correct for winter/summer difference of one hour. In both cases, we make use of the `tm_isdst` field, which `time.localtime` conveniently calculates to tell us whether **Daylight Savings Time (DST)** was in effect for a particular timestamp.

## Input Correction

If you are setting a winter timestamp during summer, or vice versa, it will become off by an hour when its matching season comes around unless you compensate before calling `SetFileTime`:

    now = time.localtime()
    createTime = Time(time.mktime(cTime_t) + 3600 * (now.tm_isdst - cTime_t.tm_isdst))
    accessTime = Time(time.mktime(aTime_t) + 3600 * (now.tm_isdst - aTime_t.tm_isdst))
    modifyTime = Time(time.mktime(mTime_t) + 3600 * (now.tm_isdst - mTime_t.tm_isdst))
    SetFileTime(fh, createTime, accessTime, modifyTime) 

## Output Correction

To make Python reports match Windows Explorer, we apply the correction before calling `strftime`:

    # check if all was ok
    now = time.localtime()
    ctime = os.path.getctime(fName)
    mtime = os.path.getmtime(fName)
    atime = os.path.getatime(fName)
    ctime += 3600 * (now.tm_isdst - time.localtime(ctime).tm_isdst)
    mtime += 3600 * (now.tm_isdst - time.localtime(mtime).tm_isdst)
    atime += 3600 * (now.tm_isdst - time.localtime(atime).tm_isdst)
    ctime = time.strftime(format,time.localtime(ctime))
    mtime = time.strftime(format,time.localtime(mtime))
    atime = time.strftime(format,time.localtime(atime))

## Both Corrections

Beware, if you apply both, your Python output will again seem to mismatch your input. This may be desirable (see below), but if it bothers you:

* Choose only _Input Correction_ if you prefer timestamps that look right at their native time of year.
* Choose only _Output Correction_ if you're used to seeing them jump an hour twice a year as DST takes effect and then goes away.

---
# Why is DST so inconsistent?

Python and Windows have chosen different methods to convert timestamps between UTC and the local time zone:

* Python uses the DST code that was in effect at the timestamp. This way, the time stamp has a consistent representation year-round.

* Windows uses the DST code in effect right now. This way, all time stamps shown have the same implicit code.

This is evident if you use '%Z' to include the time zone in the converted string (PST vs. PDT, for example) but since most apps (including Windows Explorer) do not, an apparent one-hour inconsistency can manifest.

## Example

When printed with explicit time codes, it becomes clear that the stamps in each column really do all represent the same instant in time:

    File #1 (January)        File #2 (June)
    2000-01-30 20:00:00 UTC  2000-06-22 20:00:00 UTC

    observed in January in California:
    2000-01-30 12:00:00 PST  2000-06-30 13:00:00 PDT  [Python]
    2000-01-30 12:00:00 PST  2000-06-30 12:00:00 PST  [Windows]

    observed in June in California:
    2000-01-30 12:00:00 PST  2000-06-30 13:00:00 PDT  [Python]
    2000-01-30 13:00:00 PDT  2000-06-30 13:00:00 PDT  [Windows]

    observed in June in New York:
    2000-01-30 15:00:00 EST  2000-06-30 16:00:00 EDT  [Python]
    2000-01-30 16:00:00 EDT  2000-06-30 16:00:00 EDT  [Windows]

It would be nice if we could ask strftime to honor the tm_isdst field, to match Windows Explorer and most other apps that display file timestamps, but at least there's a simple workaround to do the calculation ourselves.

    def adjustForDST (seconds):
        now = time.localtime()
        correction = 60*60 * (now.tm_isdst - time.localtime(seconds).tm_isdst)
        return seconds + correction

    time.strftime(format, time.localtime(adjustforDST(mtime)))

### Sources:
http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/655606-python-2-5-1-broken-os-stat-module
http://search.cpan.org/~shay/Win32-UTCFileTime-1.58/lib/Win32/UTCFileTime.pm

If the cpan link breaks again with a new revision, find it this way:

https://www.google.com/search?q=UTCFileTime.pm
```

Comment: Can you post the code that's giving you this issue.

Comment: Is it appropriate to post it here, in the body of my question? I'm unsure of the community standards for Meta questions.

Comment: It's okay since it's the only way we evaluate the issue.

Comment: Ok, edited to include the full markdown text.

Comment: @SeanGugler sorry, could you post the full markdown text without being indented as code? We need the exact copy since it was confusing to differentiate which are code and which are not compared to the screenshot... or you can't because it triggers the same error?

Comment: @AndrewT. I'm not sure how to do that ... if I don't quote my entire markdown, won't it be interepreted and formatted and run afoul of the same rejection? It should be evident which bits of my markdown are code quotes, they are block indented by 4 spaces.

Comment: It won't get rejected here since that code formatting check doesn't run on meta, but I agree it is pretty obvious which parts are code just looking at the markdown.

Comment: That's quite puzzling. Have you considered removing small parts of it (the links, for instance) to see if it would solve the problem? (You should be able to edit them back in later)

Comment: That explains why I could post the expected markdown (sorry for this rash action, didn't mean to do that here actually). And I agree with David, maybe you should post the most essential part of your answer, then slowly add part-by-part until you found the cause. Then report the problem back here.

Comment: I love it when diamond mods set things to status-bydesign without any comment.

Comment: @AstroCB I think your edit was not appropriate. I believe the intent here was to show - as code - the markdown code that is triggering the confusing error message - *not* to have it rendered in this post.

Comment: @AndrewMedico Good point: I forgot that MD is rendered in blockquotes.

Comment: @Haney, you've added the tag "by design" -- why do you consider this so? If my mistake was fixed by adding a blank line after a ###header line, then it seems awfully curious that the auto-validation code is specifically designed to report this as "code should be indented" and to point to the wrong location.  (Also, does anyone know how to contact Haney directly, or else how to tag him in a way I am sure he will see my inquiry?)  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2420979/haney

Comment: @SeanGugler not to worry, I respond to *all* messages aimed at me *eventually*. :) It's a quirk of markdown, and what you're talking about is an [ATX header](http://jgm.github.io/stmd/spec.html#atx-header). Our current implementation (for which there really isn't much of a standard) requires a blank line after an ATX header. The proposed specification, **CommonMark**, would not require a blank line. We are looking into adopting CommonMark specifications, but like all good things it will take some time. Hope this helps!

Comment: @Haney, thanks! Sounds good. While awaiting CommonMark, if it's straightforward to detect a malformed ATX header as distinct from malformed code indent, it could help others from getting as confused as I was. Meanwhile, maybe they'll stumble on this thread and be enlightened. Cheers!

Comment: @SeanGugler valid point. I'll take a look tomorrow. If it's "easy pickins" I'll fix it up. Thanks for the input!

Comment: @SeanGugler I still plan to investigate this. Off sick today. Will try for tomorrow.

Comment: @Haney Given that Stack Overflow has now adopted CommonMark, would it be fair to say this functionality (if it's still happening) is no longer by design?

Answer (score 29):

Apparently it wanted a blank line after the `### Sources` header near the bottom, and misreported the error to me.

I was able to successfully post it by following [DavidRobinson's](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/712603/david-robinson) suggestion in the [comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271142/why-is-my-answer-triggering-a-not-properly-formatted-as-code-rejection#comment93118_271142):

> That's quite puzzling. Have you considered removing small parts of it (the links, for instance) to see if it would solve the problem? (You should be able to edit them back in later)

I posted in two parts; first without the links, then editing it and appending the links. The edit made the complained area more obvious.

Comment: I would have used unorganized lists, instead of links.

Comment: The time/elapsed time text after "David Robinson" on his comment is a link to his comment, so if you right-click it and copy the hyperlink, it gives you the link Infinite Recursion edited into your answer. For instance, right now it says *"...back in later) –  David Robinson 2 days ago"* and the "2 days ago" is the comment link.