# Can't post due to code format error

Tags: support

I am trying to post this for hours. 
But it always prevented due to some code format issue:

> *your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code*

Please advise.

Why Python Descriptor Work for Class Level Attribute and not for an Instance Level Attribute.

```
class PropDescriptor:

    def __init__(self,*args):
        print("Init {} {}".format(type(self),args))
        self.value = 0

    def __get__ (self,instance,owner):
        print("get using descriptor")
        return instance.instance_att

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        print("set using descriptor")
        instance.instance_att = value


class TestClass:
    class_att = PropDescriptor()

    def __init__(self):
        self.instance_att = PropDescriptor()



t = TestClass()
print("set instance level...")
t.instance_att = 3

print("\nget instance level...")
print(t.instance_att)

print("\nset class level...")
t.class_att = 4

print("\nget class level...")
print(t.class_att)
```

Output:

```
Init <class '__main__.PropDescriptor'> ()
Init <class '__main__.PropDescriptor'> ()
set instance level...

get instance level...
3

set class level...
set using descriptor

get class level...
get using descriptor
4
```

looks like the descriptor is not used for the `instance_att`.

I found this [identical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428264/why-do-managed-attributes-just-work-for-class-attributes-and-not-for-instance-at) question, however I did not understand the answer.
Also read [this](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors), but I don't understand.
It is also written [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#invoking-descriptors):

> Instance Binding 
>   If binding to an object instance, a.x is transformed
>   into the call: `type(a).__dict__['x'].__get__(a, type(a))`.

But:
`type(t).__dict__["instance_att"]`, raises an *KeyError* as `type(t).__dict__`

does not have such an attribute. It is an instance level att.

What am I missing?

Comment: However -- even if you can ask this, I think this will be closed as unclear or duplicate. : "I did not understand the answer" -- Exactly what can't you understand?

Comment: @user202729 you are right. I fixed the question

Comment: What is the canonical question for this problem?

Comment: Related (different reason for posting problems): *[Make the "must be accompanied by code" warning more direct](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293510/)*. Problems with tables: *[A Markdown table is detected incorrectly as a badly formatted code block](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404314/)*

Comment: It could be this one: *[Code correctly formatted, but I still get "Your post appears to contain code..." error?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346231/)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some attempts and try to reduce the post to an MCVE, I can confirm that if it's posted from a 1-rep account, this brings up the big red box says

> Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

:

```
[Stack Overflow][1]  
[Try it online][2]  
[Programming Puzzles & Code Golf][3]

[1]: https://stackoverflow.com
[2]: https://tio.run
[3]: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com
```

(which renders as

> [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com)
>   [Try it online](https://tio.run)
>   [Programming Puzzles & Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com)

)

I guess Stack Overflow detects that by finding large block of text that contains lots of symbols (in this case, `[` and `]`). In this case it was the block of text

```
I found this [identical][1] question, however I did not understand the answer.  
Also read [this][2], but I don't understand.
It is also written [here][3]:
```

Temporary workaround: Use two newlines to split lines.

```
I found this [identical][1] question, however I did not understand the answer.

Also read [this][2], but I don't understand.
It is also written [here][3]:
```

Comment: But don't post it in the current form. (for the reason I said in the comment above)