# What is going on here? There is no code

Tags: bug, code-formatting, error-message

I tried asking a question on Stack Overflow and got a weird message saying I didn't have properly formatted code. Does anyone know what is going on here?

Putting that line in code blocks didn't make the error go away. Commenting the 3 lines above as well worked.

Someone else was able to edit [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52201081/tell-all-permutations-of-a-list) to make the formatting correct.

[image]

Comment: This is again because of SP (supposedly) using a simple algorithm to determine whether something may be code -- i.e., if it has too many symbols. In this case it's probably the 4th paragraph (aww, SO has no Latex) See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368687/cant-post-due-to-code-format-error/368692#368692