# A Markdown table is detected incorrectly as a badly formatted code block

Tags: bug, markdown, quality-filter, tables

I tried to post this on [the new tables feature thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support) on Meta Stack Exchange but I don't have enough reputation to post an answer or even a comment on the question. It might only be a Stack Overflow bug so maybe it belongs here anyway.

I tried to post this Markdown table:

```
| Number of bytes | First code point | Last code point | Byte 1 | Byte 2 | Byte 3 | Byte 4 |
| - | ------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- |
| 1 | U+0000  | U+007F   | 0xxxxxxx |          |          |          |
| 2 | U+0080  | U+07FF   | 110xxxxx | 10xxxxxx |          |          |
| 3 | U+0800  | U+FFFF   | 1110xxxx | 10xxxxxx | 10xxxxxx |          |
| 4 | U+10000 | U+10FFFF | 11110xxx | 10xxxxxx | 10xxxxxx | 10xxxxxx |
```

It formats correctly in the preview:

[image: Good preview]

But the editor claims it's a bad code block and won't let me post the answer:

[image: Warning]

Comment: Now that the announcement on MSE has been unprotected, I have added an answer there: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/359346

Comment: This is an interesting one. You managed to trip our _code formatting detection_ quality check with your table. Brief explanation: We run some heuristics against posts before they're saved to see if there are any lines that _look like_ code but aren't _marked as_ code (fenced or indented code blocks). Something in your post is tripping that check. I'll do some digging to see what exactly this is.

Comment: There are 3 [evil TAB characters](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MBWAP_8zxaM&t=9m37s) in the source for the table.

Answer (score 16):

Thanks for reporting this. I had some fun poking around and here's what I found out:

Whenever you save a post on stackoverflow.com, we run a bunch of quality checks. One of them is checking whether your post contains unformatted code - and as you can see, you tripped this one off.

Checking for unformatted code is mostly a heuristic. We look for typical keywords and characters that often appear in code and if you exceed a certain threshold within a few consecutive lines, we'll show you the *"your post appears to contain code"* warning you're seeing.

My initial hunch was that the `|` characters of your table are triggering this but this isn't it (on second thought this would be surprising because then all tables would trigger this check).

It's not the table syntax in your post that's making our code formatting check go wild. It's the many `+` characters in short succession in your code points that cause it.

As an example, a post like this (without any tables) would trigger the same check:

```
This is an example

U+0080 U+0080
U+0800
U+10000
```

A quick workaround would be to mark your code points as **inline code**. Inline code is exempt from the code formatting check.

Something like this will work:

```
| Number of bytes | First code point | Last code point | Byte 1 | Byte 2 | Byte 3 | Byte 4 |
| - | ------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- |
| 1 | `U+0000`  | `U+007F`   | 0xxxxxxx |          |          |          |
| 2 | `U+0080`  | `U+07FF`   | 110xxxxx | 10xxxxxx |          |          |
| 3 | `U+0800`  | `U+FFFF`   | 1110xxxx | 10xxxxxx | 10xxxxxx |          |
| 4 | `U+10000` | `U+10FFFF` | 11110xxx | 10xxxxxx | 10xxxxxx | 10xxxxxx |
```

| Number of bytes | First code point | Last code point | Byte 1 | Byte 2 | Byte 3 | Byte 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | `U+0000` | `U+007F` | 0xxxxxxx |  |  |  |
| 2 | `U+0080` | `U+07FF` | 110xxxxx | 10xxxxxx |  |  |
| 3 | `U+0800` | `U+FFFF` | 1110xxxx | 10xxxxxx | 10xxxxxx |  |
| 4 | `U+10000` | `U+10FFFF` | 11110xxx | 10xxxxxx | 10xxxxxx | 10xxxxxx |

Comment: until the heuristic changes tomorrow?

Comment: The last time the heuristic changed was in 2019 when balpha introduced fenced code blocks. Other than that it's been exactly the same behavior since 2011. I don't see a reason to get cynical.

Comment: Sorry I didn't meant to come across as cynical. Rather I meant to gently suggest it would be nice of it was more robust. My first guess at a solution would be to find the tables in the text, remove them with places holders, then pass the remaining text to the "might be a code block" finder rather than just keep praying that more people don't run into this. Like if you were trying to show formulas in an answer on excel you'd likely see lots of `+` symbols.

Comment: I see where you're coming from but keep in mind that this specific problem has nothing to to with tables at all. I'd argue that formulas in an excel answer qualify as code and should be marked as such. I'm really not opposed to tweaking the heuristics but from my (limited, I'll admit that) experience, they have proven to work kinda okay and I wouldn't want to fix this issue and introduce a host of new ones. Hope that sounds reasonable. If you find other issues, please let me know and we can revisit!

Comment: I had exactly this problem today apparently because my table includes `=` signs. It was kind of irritating to read "appears to contain code" in the message when that was not the case; it would have really been nice to have a check mark "yes I saw the message but my post does not contain unformatted code so please save the edit."

Comment: @HamVocke Could making the discussed error message more transparent for the users be an option? E.g. by listing (the most commonly used) characters that tend to trigger it?

Comment: `+` really causing the problem in table rows