# Why do these tables stop my question from being submitted to Stack Overflow?

Tags: support

## Tables appear correct in preview, but appear as code to Stack Overflow's checkers

The *tables* in my questions look good in preview, but Stack Overflow's checkers won't let me submit. How do I change my tables to allow them to be pretty and successfully submitted?

## Here are the input tables:

### visit_df

| CUST_ID | VISIT_ID | VISIT_DTM |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2009-08-28 00:00:00.000000 |
| 1 | 2 | 2009-08-31 00:00:00.000000 |
| 20 | 11 | 2009-08-27 00:00:00.000000 |
| 20 | 21 | 2009-08-31 00:00:00.000000 |

### customer_df

| CUST_ID | ATTR | START_DTM | END_DTM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 'RED' | 2008-08-27 00:00:00.000000 | 2008-08-28 00:00:00.000000 |
| 1 | 'BLUE' | 2008-08-28 00:00:00.000000 | 2010-08-28 00:00:00.000000 |
| 1 | 'BLACK' | 2009-08-29 00:00:00.000000 | 2010-08-28 00:00:00.000000 |
| 20 | 'YELLOW' | 2008-08-26 00:00:00.000000 | 2009-08-28 00:00:00.000000 |
| 20 | 'BLUE' | 2008-08-28 00:00:00.000000 | 2010-08-28 00:00:00.000000 |
| 20 | BLACK | 2009-08-29 00:00:00.000000 | 2010-09-03 00:00:00.000000 |

## Here is the desired result

### Result named augmented visit_df in the slow code

| CUST_ID | VISIT_ID | VISIT_DTM | ATTR_STR | ATTR_ARRAY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2009-08-28 00:00:00.000000 | 'BLUE' | ['BLUE'] |
| 1 | 2 | 2009-08-31 00:00:00.000000 | 'BLUE-BLACK' | ['BLUE',BLACK'] |
| 20 | 11 | 2009-08-27 00:00:00.000000 | 'YELLOW-BLUE' | ['YELLOW','BLUE'] |
| 20 | 21 | 2009-08-31 00:00:00.000000 | 'BLUE-BLACK' | ['BLUE','BLACK'] |

Comment: Of course they submitted here! But why not here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69693179/how-to-efficiently-join-merge-multiple-data-frames-subject-to-conditions-in-the

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A Markdown table is detected incorrectly as a badly formatted code block](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404314/a-markdown-table-is-detected-incorrectly-as-a-badly-formatted-code-block) So wrap whatever has to do with code in inline code and it will work.

Comment: "*Of course they submitted here! But why not here?*" there's no post quality check on meta.

Comment: The linked post is a workaround and I used it to submit my question, but I am not able to post the pretty tables. Maybe some trial and error and I can figure just what about the tables is triggering the review. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404314/a-markdown-table-is-detected-incorrectly-as-a-badly-formatted-code-block